# Edit WooCommerce default alert verbiage in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a correct, update-proof method for editing default system alerts and verbiage used by the WooCommerce WordPress plugin? (This question probably applies to all WordPress plugins, but WooCommerce is my specific concern right now.)

As a simple example, let's say I want to change "Your password has been reset successfully" to "Your password has been set". The current verbiage is specific to WooCommerce and exists in these two files:

1. /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce.pot
2. /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php

If I hardcode my edit into the second file, it works but risks getting overwritten when updating the plugin. Is there a correct way to do this that's update-proof?

Comment: Depends on the case if you go multilang or just want to change strings on current language. If its single lang website and you need to change 1-2 things and not rewrite all of the texts then use gettext filter. The pot file is used to generate po mo files which do the translation. I would not recommend overwriting entire po,mo files due to when woocommerce update you will be missing new strings and you have to check for that too. Use plugins like Loco or WPML to overwrite what you dont like that would be the safer option if you dont have exp with that.

Comment: In case you want to go with po mo files i would recommend to create your own "language" en_ZZ or something and set your woo to use that "language". For all new strings you will have to update your po mo files. Use program like Eazy Po to help you.

Comment: For the notices you can use filter provided by woo.

Comment: Thank you, @Snuffy — I couldn't have asked for a more comprehensive answer. The customized language pack idea is brilliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For notices you can use `woocommerce_add_notice` filter.

```
function custom_reset_password_confirmation_message( $message, $notice_type ) {
    // Check if it's the password reset notice
    if ( 'success' === $notice_type && ! empty( $_GET['password-reset'] ) ) {
        // Modify the password reset success message
        $message = __( 'Your password has been set.', 'your-text-domain' );
    }

    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'custom_reset_password_confirmation_message', 10, 2 );
```